# Delete using checkbox in php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, checkbox, pgwmodal

I have a problem with deleting the checked items in the data because my delete button is not part of the for loop where I get my data from the database that's why I'm having a hard time getting the ID of the data that is to be deleted. I can do a single delete with the javascript `modaldelete` but I can't implement the same thing with the checkbox since the delete button is not inside the table and it wouldn't be a good sight if you put the delete button beside the checkbox since it has a for loop for each item in the table. And now I can't figure out how will I get the values from the selected checkbox. What is the more appropriate way in solving this? PHP or javascript? Which is more efficient in the two language?

Here are my code snippet:

```
 <div style="font-size:16px;">
    Search: <input id="filter" type="text" style="height:1em;"/>
    <p class="pull-right">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modaladdclient" data-id="add">Add</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modaldelete" data-id="add">Delete</a> &nbsp;
    </p>
 </div>

    <?php 
            $statement="SELECT * FROM clients";                 
            $result = mysqlparser($statement, $db);

    ?>
      <table data-filter="#filter" class="footable" style="background-color:white;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Client ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th data-sort-initial="ascending">Last Name</th>
                <th>Mobile Number</th>
                <th>Branch Code</th>
                <th data-sort-ignore="true" colspan="2">Options</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++){?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $result[$i]['Client_ID'];?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $result[$i]['First_Name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result[$i]['Last_Name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $result[$i]['Mobile_Number'];?></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modalbid" data-id="<?php echo    $result[$i]['Branch_Code'];?>"><?php echo $result[$i]['Branch_Code'];?></a></td>
                <td class="text-right"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modaledit" data-id="<?php echo $result[$i]['Client_ID'];?>"><button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button></a></td>
                <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name=<?php echo $result[$i]['Client_ID'];?>></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }
            if(count($result)==0)
            {
                echo "<tr><td colspan='5' style='text-align:center; font-weight:bold;'>No data available</td></tr>";
            }
            else
            {}
            ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="8">
                    <div class="pagination pagination-centered"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
   <script>
    $('.modaldelete').click(function() {
        $.pgwModal({
            url: 'submit.php?action=delete&from=clients&col=Client_ID&id='+$(this).data('id'),
            loading: '<span style="text-align:center">Loading in progress</span>',
            close: false
        });
    });
 </script>
```

This is my submit.php

```
if($_GET['action']=="delete")
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
$from = $_GET['from'];
$col = $_GET['col'];

$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];

for($i=0; $i<count($checkbox);$i++)
{
    $del_id = $checkbox[$i];

    $statement = "DELETE FROM `".$from."` WHERE `".$col."`='".$del_id."'";
    $result = mysqlparser($statement, $db);
    header("location:data_client.php?delete=1");        

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use onchange in that checkbox. You can than call a confirm() at first and after that delete the entry.

onchange="myFunction()"

Comment: what is that myFunction? javascript?

Comment: Yes, it is a placeholder for your own function you can call from this place. You can write one to ask the user for a confirmation and delete after that is done.